# How can I $watch multiple values

Tags: angularjs

My listener function depends on several values and I need to put $watch on each of them.  I have thought of two ways:

```
scope.$watch(function() { return [calcOneValue(), calcTheOtherValue()]; },
             function(a) { return theListener(a[0], a[1]); });
```

or

```
scope.$watch(calcOneValue,
             function(a) { return theListener(a, calcTheOtherValue()); });

scope.$watch(calcTheOtherValue,
             function(a) { return theListener(calcOneValue(), a); });
```

Are these the right ways to do this?  Is there a better third option I am missing?

Should I genericize this, make a function that takes a scope, an array of value functions and one, multi-parameter listener function?  Or does such a function already exist?  Or does $watch do this already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular has a built-in way to invoke the same function when any of specified expressions change - with [`$watchGroup`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24watchGroup):

```
$scope.$watchGroup(["foo", "bar"], function(newValues, oldValues){
   // do something when either $scope.foo or $scope.bar changes
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can deep watch an array by setting the third value of the call to true, and then put all your values in an array if you want.

```
 scope.$watch(myArray,function() { ...},true);
```